# Plotting PDFs of circular random variables in R (polar plots)

Tags: r, plot, diagram

I am trying to find a sensible way of visualising probability density functions of circular random variables in R. The most appropriate way of doing so is on a polar plot. However, I am not sure how to code this in R. Can someone illustrate how this can be done, using the [wrapped exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_exponential_distribution) as an example? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: There's a `circular` package. I thought it had a plot method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ezpolar` function from pkg:pracma gives a more typical polar plot than `plotrix::radial.plot`, however it is like the base graphics function `curve` in that it takes a functional argument.

```
if(!require(pracma) ){ 
         install.packages("pracma", dependencies=TRUE); library(pracma) }
?ezpolar
wrapped.exp <- function(theta, lambda){ 
                      lambda*exp(-lambda*theta)/(1-exp(-2*pi*lambda) )}
theta <- seq(0, 2*pi, len=100)

# since it requires a functional argument with only one variable,
# I'm defining a separate helper function with predefined lambda

  png() ;  wrap.2 <- function(x) wrapped.exp(x,.2)
           ezpolar(wrap.2); dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The circular package seems focused on vonMises distribution. You can roll your own wrapped exponential probability distribution:

```
wrapped.exp <- function(theta, lambda){ 
                          lambda*exp(-lambda*theta)/(1-exp(-2*pi*lambda) )}
```

And use plotrix package's `radial.plot`:

```
theta <- seq(0, 2*pi, len=100)
rval <- wrapped.exp(theta, .2)
# radial.plot's default radial limits are just the range so not really good for distributions.
radial.plot(rval,theta, radial.lim=c(0, 0.4))
```

[image]

Plotting code:

```
> png()
> rval <- wrapped.exp(theta, .2)
> radial.plot(rval,theta, radial.lim=c(0, 0.4))
> dev.off()
```

I would note that the "wrapped exponential" formula is not actually a true mathematical function on the closed interval `[0, 2*pi]` since this function would have two values at 0 = 2*pi, so it probably should have code to make any theta + or > 2*pi to be NA or something "mod 2*pi". Further note: That formula is really just a truncated exponential at 2*pi. Since it is a truncated density it seems that it should not have a 0 value at 2*pi. Appears that radial plot uses the range of the radial vector rather than going from 0 to maximum. Seems that it should default instead to c(0, range(lambda)[2]). When I get time I will correct this answer.

Comment: Is there a way of displaying the pdf as a a curve rather than as a series of lines emanating from the pole?

Comment: Yes, it is possible with additional searching to find such a function. The one I found does seem to give a  different result and to my eyes it appears more correct. Looking at the result above I'm not entirely happy with it. I'm going to send an email to the maintainer and primary author of plotrix explaining my concerns.

Comment: I see what you mean. Though in most of the literature distributions are compared using curved plots. If you could improve your answer with such a depictions I would happy approve your answer.

Comment: I'm going to put up a separate answer, since invloves a different package and function.